# Is it wise to display data base errors

Tags: php

I am looking to secure the db connection file.
- Is it wise to report data base errors like I have displayed. May be attacker could figure out a way in by reading into db errors?
- Can someone please give an example how can I safely create db connection file?
Following is my code to connect to the file:

```php
<?php
//Error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'customer_accounts';
$conn= $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
```

Comment: No, log the error or send a message to yourself and show a nice error message without technical information to the visitor.

Comment: @jeroen *b-b-b-b-but...* what if they want to? *haha!*

Answer (score 1):

From [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Improper_Error_Handling):

> Improper handling of errors can introduce a variety of security problems for a web site. The most common problem is when detailed internal error messages such as stack traces, database dumps, and error codes are displayed to the user (hacker). These messages reveal implementation details that should never be revealed. Such details can provide hackers important clues on potential flaws in the site and such messages are also disturbing to normal users... These errors must be handled according to a well thought out scheme that will provide a meaningful error message to the user, diagnostic information to the site maintainers, and no useful information to an attacker.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db)
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    // Diagnostic information to the site maintainers
    error_log($mysqli->connect_error);
    // A meaningful error message to the user
    // No useful information to an attacker
    echo "Server error";
}
```